# Computed column at creation of table gets evaluated every time

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I have the following script that creates a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Persons] 
(
    [Id]            INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]          NVARCHAR(250)     NOT NULL,
    [Surname]       NVARCHAR(250)     NOT NULL,
    [NumberOfNotes] INT               NOT NULL,
    [TotalCash]     FLOAT             NOT NULL,
    [Result] AS ([NumberOfNotes] * [TotalCash] * ROUND(RAND() * 2, 0)),

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Persons] PRIMARY KEY ([Id] ASC)
);
```

The table gets created correctly and whenever I insert a new person the `Result` gets calculated. Problem is that it gets re-evaluated every time I do a select. I would like the computed value to stay the same for that record. How do I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simple trick is to seed `rand()`:

```
[Result] AS ([NumberOfNotes] * [TotalCash] * ROUND(RAND(id) * 2, 0)),
```

Basically, this is using a "deterministic" random number generator.  You can do that in other ways as well.

Alternatively, you could just assign it a value when you insert new rows into the table.

Comment: Does the column also have to be marked as 'persisted'?

Comment: @ScottMildenberger . . . If you build an index on it or if you don't want it recalculated.  However, the seed makes `rand()` stable, so running it multiple times returns the same value.

Comment: The constant recalculation sounds slightly wasteful. Since the value is supposed to be frozen, there is no point using a computed column.

Comment: First of all thank you! I think I am missing something then.. let's make the formula easier just for the sake of this exercise. Let's say that when I add a record in my table the **result** info is something I don't have and I want it to be generated on the fly as ** [NumberOfNotes] * [TotalCash] * SomeRandomNumber** . How do I achieve this in such a way the value stays there for each record and it's really random?

Comment: will actually created a new question since you answered my question I think it's fair to make a new one!